# Moving 0's in a list without interfering the order of other non-zero items

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to solve a programming quiz on Leet Code. The question is:

Given an integer array nums, move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.

Note that you must do this in-place without making a copy of the array.

### Example 1:

Input: nums = [0,1,0,3,12]

Output: [1,3,12,0,0]

### Example 2:

Input: nums = [0]

Output: [0]

### Constraints:

1 <= nums.length <= 104

-231 <= nums[i] <= 231 - 1

### My solution

```py
class Solution:
    def moveZeroes(self, nums: List[int]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        count = 0
        for item in nums:
            if item == 0:
                nums.remove(item)
                count += 1                
        for i in range(0,count):
            nums.append(0)
```

What my solution is trying to do is that:

1. It traverses the entire list.
2. If any item is 0, the item is removed. The counter increments by 1.
3. After traversing the list, append `counter` number of 0's to the list.

However, my solution didn't pass the following test case.

### Test input:

[0,0,1]

### Expected output:

[1,0,0]

### My output:

[0,1,0]

Where does my script go wrong?

Comment: Have you debugged your code? With such small inputs you can easily print out the intermediate results of all the steps. Using an interactive debugger is another option.

Comment: Your function will not work for any consecutive 0's in array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in a simple way:

```
>>> nums = [0,1,0,3,12]
>>> output=[i for i in nums if i!=0]
>>> for cnt in range(nums.count(0)):
       output.extend("0")

    
>>> print(output)
[1, 3, 12, '0', '0']
```

Same code can be convert into one liner solution as suggested by @deadshot:

```
[i for i in nums if i!=0] + [0] * nums.count(0)
```

Comment: `[i for i in nums if i!=0] + [0] * nums.coun(0)` one liner, you can avoid for loop this way

Comment: But the question requires us to do it in-place, without creating a new list.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer together with the one line solution from comment are nice pythonic solutions. If you really need the same list modified in place you can do something similar with bubble-sort, swap elements until all the zeroes are at the end.

```
nums = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12]
done = False

while not done:
    done = True
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        if nums[i] == 0 and nums[i + 1] != 0:
            nums[i] = nums[i + 1]
            nums[i + 1] = 0
            done = False

print(nums)
```

In your solution, `remove` removes only the first occurrence or a zero. To make it work you need to remove until there are no zeros remaining and then append the final number of zeroes at the end.

Comment: One more question, in my script, I used a `for` loop to traverse through the list. Does the "for" loop ensure that the remove operation is called every time it encounters a 0? Why is the remove() method called only once in my script even if I used a for loop?

Comment: when you remove an elem from a list in for loop it shifts its internal index, so you are skipping every other element. that's why it works for [0,1,0] and not for [0,0,1]. After removing first 0 you skip second elem and compare 3rd.

Comment: @mx0 Thanks! You clarified my most outstanding doubt!